# The empty set contains irrationals only.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the above statement true; because we can not find any rational in it.
Or false; because it does not contain any irrational.

Also is the statement: "The elements of the empty set are irrationals and no element in it is rational." true, being vacuous?

Comment: It contains empty elements.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima If you mean "It contains no elements," that's true, but as you've written it, it sounds like you're saying it has elements that are the emptyset, and that would be incorrect.

Comment: Part of the disorienting effect of the statement is this: "The empty set contains irrationals" is obviously false, but the *only* changes the meaning completely. That leads to the interpretation outlined by Mohit.

Comment: The grammar of English can be confusing.  In baseball, extra-large sticks are carried by goalies only. True, as there are no goalies in baseball.

Comment: The empty set contains the Answer To The Universe, Why We Are Here  and Everything Else...

Comment: @Raffaele: Unfortunately, that is not true. $42\notin\varnothing$.

Answer (score 6):

Yes the statement is true. It can be rephrased as if $x \in \emptyset$ then $x \in \mathbb Q^c$. Since the hypothesis $x\in \emptyset$ is false the statement as a whole is by definition true.

Another way to think about this is that the statement "if $x \in \emptyset$ then $x \in \mathbb Q^c$" is that same as saying that $\emptyset$ is a subset of $\mathbb Q^c$ which is also vacuously true.

Answer (score 2):

We say that a set $A$ has only irrational numbers if $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$.

The empty set is a subset of *every* set. Therefore it is indeed correct to say that it only has irrational numbers as elements. It is also true to say that it has pink elephants as elements, as well as almond milk and tofu cheese, or snarks and grumplings.

Another way of looking at this is to say that $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ has only irrational numbers if $A\cap\Bbb Q$ is empty, i.e. if $A$ is disjoint from $\Bbb Q$. And again, $\varnothing\cap\Bbb Q$ is indeed empty.

Comment: A set contains irrationals if it certains contains one. Further it contains only irrationals if it contains no rational.

Comment: The problem with mathematical English is that it is often confused with natural language. No, a set contains only irrational numbers if all of its elements are irrational numbers. Nobody said anything about any elements existing.

Comment: Does not "I have only pens" imply I have one? If not, then why "I have pens" imply at least one. Whereas, the first statement could be true only when the second is. Or shall I think like this: since all the elements of the empty set are irrationals, and therefore it contains only irrationals.

Comment: Yes, but "All my pens are black" does not imply that you have any pens.

Comment: Let A⊆R containing 2 only. Does it still imply A could be empty?

Comment: Again, this comes from a natural language ambiguity. When you specify only a single element (or two, or five) then it is either unclear if you mean exactly these elements or a subset of that.

Comment: I mean 2 as an element.

Comment: So your question is "is the set {2} empty"?

Comment: No, my this question follows the theme of my main question, with the replacement of 'irrationals' by '2'. Wherein you expressed a set containing irrationals only could be empty. So I just took your words to particularity in this question; arguing how could a set containing only 2 (as an element) be empty?

Comment: I have no idea why you accepted my question, honestly. You seem entirely dissatisfied with it. To your comment, *again*, this is an issue with natural language and ambiguity. You literally claimed to mean a set with one element. So it is not empty. But common mathematical jargon dictates that in other situations it has a different meaning. Just like "left" and "right" both have different meanings in different contexts. I honestly don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $$\forall x \in \emptyset: x \text{ is irrational}$$

holds but also

$$\forall x \in \emptyset: x \text{ is rational}$$

holds as well. Proof: if it doesn't hold, there should be a counterexample.
But there is no element in $\emptyset$ to be a counterexample.

Read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) on vacuous truth, e.g.